# ms-word template named-styles conversion

Tags: ms-word

In MS Word 2010, when I apply a dotx template to a docx files and different styles exist in the two docs, how can I map a list of styles from the former to a list of differently-named styles from the latter?

Let me clarify the issue.
I have a dotx style file with a few standard styles (ex. heading1, caption etc.) and a few other styles (ex. blockquote, superfigure etc.). I must use this template and cannot change nor add any names there.

I have a document preparation system (ex. pandoc, orgmode) that outputs a docx file. When I compare some of the styles used in this docx I see they have a different name compared to the previous dotx, yet the "meaning" is the same. For example the "blockquote" of the dotx should be applied to the parts of the docx that are marked as "quotedtext".

SO, how can I tell MS Word 2010 to apply the dotx style to my docx mapping "blockquote" to "quotedtext"? Any alternative solution using different tecnologies like xls transform or similar stuff?

Any hint would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the Home tab, click the *widget* (little arrow in the corner) of the Styles group to display the Styles pane. Click the Manage Styles icon at the bottom, then the Import/Export button at the bottom-left.

[image]

In this dialog you can Copy styles across documents or templates, Rename and Delete them. If the other document or template is not open, click Close File (the right button) then Open File (the button-text changes to this).

Unfortunately, you cannot just switch one style for another (at least, not from here; see below). However, I believe the process of Copy, Rename and Delete could achieve the same effect.

Alternatively, press Ctrl-H for the Replace dialog and press the More>> button. Place the cursor in the 'Find What' box, then Format at the bottom-left, and Style... Choose the style you want to replace. Do the same in the 'Replace with' box. However, the style you want to replace with needs to be available in the current document. Use the sequence outlined above to first bring across the styles you need into the current document. A quick way to bring in all the styles from the other document or template is to copy content from this doc/template to the bottom of the current document, deleting it later.

It is also possible to use the Styles dialog (mentioned above) to modify styles, changing the **Style Based on** property. However, I wouldn't recommend this approach. You will need to be very thorough and be fully aware of the consequences of the *cascade*; that is, how each modification affects other styles in the document.

If you need to go through this process for a large number of styles then use the macro recorder. You'll then need to modify the generated code, putting it in a loop.